# Allocate objects in continuous memory section in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to implement an object pool that allocates all it's objects in a continuous section of memory. My goal is to achieve fastest possible iteration speed by avoiding cache misses.

The object pool should only contain objects of the same type and it should be possible to increase the pool size while keeping the allocated memory continuous.

How can I achieve this in Dart?

Comment: For example in Java it could be done using sun.misc.unsafe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently not possible to control where in memory Dart objects are allocated.

One workaround would be to create custom method for each pooled Dart object to pack into dart:typed_data lists. However that only works if the Dart object can be represented by the types available in dart:typed_data package.